# Play-Framework: Causing a 'IllegalArgumentException occured

Tags: java, playframework

The error I get is `'IllegalArgumentException occured' Can not set java.util.ArrayList field mi.types.ListOfObjects.objects to java.util.LinkedList`

I'm doing the following...

```
 ListOfObjects objects = li.getUsersObjects();
```

which works perfectly fine normally, however when I do the exact same call with the exact same code inside of Play it doesn't. I'm calling it in my Security Controller inside the `authenticate()` function. There's a case where the users objects are gotten from an external server. That's when this call is made. It works fine without Play and I'm pretty sure worked before I put it in the Security Controller. Why would putting it here cause such a problem?

**EDIT**

`ListOfObjects` is a custom object which contains some values.. It's located inside `li` which is a library I'm importing. It looks something like this...

```
public class ListOfObjects {

  private ArrayList<Object> objects;

  public ArrayList<Object> getObjects(){
          return objects;
   }
}
```

`getUserObjects` simply returns the objects for that user. It grabs them from a server and then uses `gson` to parse them. However I'm getting the above error when I attempt to.

**EDIT2**

No matter what I do my type for getUserObjects seems to always be returning as a LinkedList even though it's an ArrayList object. I've tried calling `getObjects()` directly and there's no change.

**EDIT 3**

getUserObjects is defined as...

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
    ListOfObjects objects = gson.fromJson(r.getBody(), ListOfObjects.class);
```

StackTrace...

where `r.getBody()` is the JSON response from the server

```
   Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Security.java around line 57)
 IllegalArgumentException occured : Can not set java.util.ArrayList field     lm.types.ListOfObjects.objects to java.util.LinkedList

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Can not set java.util.ArrayList field lm.types.ListOfObjects.objects to java.util.LinkedList
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:227)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.ArrayList field lm.types.ListOfObjects.objects to java.util.LinkedList
at com.google.gson.FieldAttributes.set(FieldAttributes.java:188)
at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:118)
at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.navigateClassFields(ObjectNavigator.java:158)
at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:131)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:73)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:51)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:568)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:515)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:484)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:434)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:406)
at lm.lib.LMethods.getUsersObjects(LMethods.java:165)
at controllers.Security.createNewUser(Security.java:57)
at controllers.Security.authenticate(Security.java:36)
at play.utils.Java.invokeStaticOrParent(Java.java:159)
at controllers.Secure$Security.invoke(Secure.java:193)
at controllers.Secure$Security.access$0(Secure.java:184)
at controllers.Secure.authenticate(Secure.java:64)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:540)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:498)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:474)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:469)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:157)
... 1 more
```

Debugger failed to attach: recv failed during handshake: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Can you post more code? What is `ListOfObject`, `li`, `getUsersObjects()`?

Comment: @axtavt I've updated my question with some code / explanation.

Comment: How is getUsersObjects() defined?  I need to see the complete stacktrace, not only the error message

Comment: @mbknor I've added both stacktrace and more info about `getUsersObjects()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception message clearly says that Gson deserializes list as `LinkedList`, whereas field of your `ListOfObjects` is declared as `ArrayList`.

The general rule to avoid this kind of problems is not to use implementation classes in field declarations. Use `List` instead:

```
public class ListOfObjects {
    private List<Object> objects; 
    ...
}
```